# Passing variable from @Injectable to Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, twilio

In the code block beneath this paragraph you can see `Twilio.Device.incoming`, there I am setting `this.connection` to `conn`.

```
@Injectable()
    export class BaMsgCenterService {
        public getData;
        public incomingCall = false;
        public connection;

        constructor(private http: Http) {
            this.initTwilio();

            Twilio.Device.ready(function (device) {
                self.incomingCall = true;
                $(".card-title").text("Ready to receive incoming calls!");
            });

            Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
               console.log(conn.status);
               this.incomingCall = true;
               this.connection = conn;
            });
            //other functions
         }
    }
}
```

Than I have a component class:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import {BaMsgCenterService} from './baMsgCenter.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'ba-msg-center',
   providers: [BaMsgCenterService],
   styleUrls: ['./baMsgCenter.scss'],
   templateUrl: './baMsgCenter.html'
})
export class BaMsgCenter {
   public connection;

   constructor(private _baMsgCenterService:BaMsgCenterService) {
      this.connection = this._baMsgCenterService.connection;
   }
   pickup() {
       this.connection.accept();
  }

}
```

In the html code I have a `(click)="pickup()"`

However, when I click it, it says that the conn does not exist.

`inline template:63:10 caused by: Cannot read property 'accept' of undefined`

I would like to make that pickup function work, it has to be able to use conn (or this.connection) in that pickup function. I think that the Twilio.Device is executed later (it is an API)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set `this.connection = this_baMsgCenterService.connection` in the constructor, you are not tying the two variables together, you are simply pointing `this.connection` at the same place `this._baMsgCenterService.connection is pointing, which is`undefined`at the time. When`this._baMsgCenterService.connection`is updated it doesn't change`this.connection`.

Here's a simpler example of that:

```
var a, b;
a = b = "foo";
b = "bar";
console.log(a); // "foo";
console.log(b); // "bar";
```

You need to keep referring to the message center service's connection. You might do this with an instance method instead of a property.

Something like:

```
export class BaMsgCenter {
   constructor(private _baMsgCenterService:BaMsgCenterService) {}

   pickup() {
     this.connection().accept();
   }

   connection() {
     this._baMsgCenterService.connection;
   }
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

**Edit**

I still think I answered half the question, but the answers regarding the context of `this` in the event are correct as well.

Comment: Yeah but he's using either the wrong language syntax or the wrong language semantics depending on how you look at it so this will not help.

Comment: I think I answered the issue that will come up once the first problem is solved with your answer. :)

Comment: Fair enough ;-]

Comment: Thank you @philnash your answer solved my challenge once again.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
(conn) => {
```

instead of

```
function (conn) {
```

also change all other occurences of `function` to the arrow functiin style, otherwise `this.` won't point to the service or compinent class as you expect.

Comment: That will help here but sometimes you actually need to use `function` to talk to certain, arguably poorly designed, APIs. Fortunately such situations are rare

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong `this`. When using the `function` syntax, `this` is bound dynamically to the target of an invocation, which is to say it is bound to the object on which the function is called when used as a method. You have two options.

Alias `this` using a local variable for use in the closure:

```
var that = this;

takesAFunction(function (value) {
  that.prop = value;
});
```

If you are targeting modern versions of NodeJS or modern browsers, or if you have access to a transpiler; such as TypeScript, Babel or Traceur; just use an ES2015 arrow function:

```
takesAFunction(value => {
  this.prop = value;
});
```

Inside of an arrow function `this` is statically scoped, also known as lexically scoped, like every other identifier in the language.

The second approach leads to clearer code and should be preferred where available.

Answer (score 0):

One error is that the base service sets the `connection` lazily. In the constructor/initialization it is not yet there, and therefore initialized to undefined. I guess you are starting an async operation here to get it, and in the callback stores it in the service:

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
    console.log(conn.status);
    this.incomingCall = true;
    this.connection = conn;
});
```

What you now may need to do is wait in the BaMsgCenter until the connection is available. E.g. by creating BasMsgCenter only when the connection is there. Or by making it a Promise in the base service or adding another promise that signals availability, subscribe from the MsgCenter to this and only use the connection once it's assigned. If you can guarantee that `pickup` is only called when the connection was assigned previously it's not necessary.

Another error is like Günter Zöchbauer also pointed out that `this` does not really point to the instance of your `BaMsgCenterService` class, which can be fixed by using an arrow function instead.